# Turn down Nintendo Switch volume when docked?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I have a Nintendo Switch docked and attached to a TV via an HDMI cable, and the volume on it is way too loud. I have to turn the TV volume down to 10 for it to be a reasonable volume. When I'm watching TV or playing on another console the volume is closer to 70. I have to remember to turn the volume down every time I turn on the Switch to avoid blasting the house.

When the Switch is docked the hardware volume buttons don't have any effect, and there is no volume option in the home menu. I've undocked it and turned the volume all the way down, but this has no effect when I dock it again.

Is there any way to control the Switch volume when it's attached to a TV?

Comment: A volume of 70 looks a bit high as the standard setting, maybe the Switch is not your main problem

Comment: Agreed with @pinckerman... I've never experienced or heard of such a thing happening. Have you confirmed it is _definitely_ the switch/switch dock? Have you plugged the switch dock into a different hdmi input on your TV? Used a different hdmi cord? Plugged the whole switch dock into a different TV/hdmi display? If so, same results?